# Bottle: @delete route breaks when I import sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bottle

I have a very simple CRUD API:

```
from bottle import get, post, put, delete, run

@get('/items/')
@get('/items')
def item_list():
    return "LIST"

@get('/items/<upc>')
def item_show( upc="0000" ):
    return "SHOW ITEM WITH UPC " + upc

@delete('/items/<upc>')
def item_delete( upc="0000" ):
    return "DELETE ITEM WITH UPC " + upc

@put('/items/<upc>')
def item_save( upc="0000" ):
    return "SAVE ITEM WITH UPC " + upc

@post('/items/<upc>')
def item_create( upc="0000" ):
    return "CREATE ITEM WITH UPC " + upc

run()
```

This works fine, I can run the server and hit all the endpoints and get the correct strings back. But if I add:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
```

to the top then when I try to run the server I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    def item_delete( upc="0000" ):
TypeError: 'Delete' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `sqlalchemy` has something with the name `delete` which overrides the `from bottle import delete`.

You can solve this by instead doing just `import sqlalchemy` or just importing the functions you need from `sqlalchemy` (like `from sqlalchemy import function_you_need, object_you_need`).

Comment: Thanks! When I narrowed it down to only what I was using it worked fine.